# Repository Pattern: Where do complex methods go?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I'm pretty sure I've got a good understanding of how to implement Repository Pattern, but I'm getting stuck in a decision loop regarding complex queries/methods.

If I want to get all users or users that have a certain field value on the user table, it's pretty clear that would go in the User repository.  However, what if I have a much more complicated query-- such as All users who have completed a video course where the video course is of such type?  In my model this query crosses about 6 tables.

I want to be able to us a repository to do something like  if(user.completedVideoRequirement), but I'm having a hard time convincing myself that the user repository is the place for this.  It seems right to me, but I could argue myself out of it pretty easily.

What's the right way?

EDIT: What if I'm returning information other than Database entities (i.e return true/false or some other int).  Should this even happen at the repository level, or should I do something like if(users.CompletedVideoRequirement.Any()) instead?
I guess it makes sense to me for this to still be on the User repository, because it's information about a user, but technically, it's also information about a video.

Comment: Are you using ef? If yes, then you should have a context with all the tables in the system. If yes, then you can access any table from one repository that has that context. What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought process is "what am I returning"?  Since the answer here is "Users" then the UserRepository is indeed the correct repo.
in order to take advantage of your Database's query optimization, you might have a hundred different ways to filter users, those would all go in the UserRepo. (ok a hundred might be overkill)

Anytime you nee a user or a collection of users, you should be able to go to the UserRepository to get it.  That's it's purpose in life, to give you users however you need them filtered.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it perfectly answers the original phrasing of the question.  Also, I imagine it will work for the edited version.  I've edited the question to include methods that do not return database objects as results (ie. t/f, int)